# Setting Up a JavaEE app on an Arduino Yun Board

Tags: arduino-yun, java

I'm looking for some reference material to start on a project I'd like to do.

I have an Open House at my school. My group project has been to create a little timesheet app using JavaEE. I just started looking for how to do this and if I can. But I would like to wow people a bit by setting this up using an Arduino Yun board. I know it has WiFi and I'm pretty sure I can run Linux on the little guy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, forget it. 64Mb ram, 16Mb flash what the Yun has.
Java EE is magnitudes bigger (and bugger) than that.

You might try with Java SE embedded, the smallest profile might fit to 11Mb:
http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/oracle-javase-embedded-ds-365290.pdf
and then you can roll your own web server.

(Personal comments: For little timesheets JavaEE is overkill, for anything modern JavaEE is obsolete - consider modern Java micro web frameworks, which offer magnitudes better performance than JavaEE).

What you can try is Raspberry PI, which works well with network, and Java (SE).
Not that well but also Java EE works: https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/glassfish_4_on_the_raspberry

Comment: Unfortunately we have to use JavaEE thank you for your support. I have acquired a Raspberry Pi 2 I will post my results :)

Comment: I am developing enterprise software for 20+ years, and I know that many companies still stick to JavaEE (for some really really awkward and twisted reasoning). On the other hand, many professionals say that JavaEE is obsolete for 10+ years, basically since the advent of Java microframeworks and full stack frameworks. Which are quite mature, and surprisingly good. :)